# Why is linux faster than IIS for downloads?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, iis

I have a Verizon FIOS 50/20 internet setup.  My servers are in a Tier III+ data center (pryme.net) in Ashburn, no limits on my rack, GiGe everything, etc.  I can download a file from a linux box behind my firewall at 6 MB/sec, yet on Windows 2003 (IIS 6) I only get 2.7 MB/sec.

Why is it that linux can provide a faster file download than Windows?

Is there anything that can be done in IIS to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You're comparing an operating system to a web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrate the IIS application to linux? :-)

Seriously, though, try tweaking some of the TCP options on the windows server machine. Specifically the TCP window max size and window scaling values. These are both registry tweaks.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224829) is some more information on the topic.

Comment: Why does a sprinter run faster than an overweight sysadmin?  Fat bloated things are just slower. ;-)  All kidding aside, +1 for checking on the Windows TCP options.  That is way too much of a speed difference to be bloat... so I was thinking configuration as well...

Comment: +2 for migrate :-) I also agree with checking the config. The service is probably just running a standard windows config which tends to run slower than linux.